# Dynamic Column Selection Menu and formula generator

Tags: php, forms, frontend, dynamic-programming

How to create a dynamic menu in php html page wherein user can do all of following from front end:

I want that to create a two column window that displays different db col names from different tables. First window shows options for selection while, second window shows options selected and arthimetic operations on them from front end. We can save and create the output of these operations over selected columns into a new table or column of output. We can reuse this formula every time..since we have saved it by simply pulling the result col and echo it on a page.

Example: user selects a database column (e.g. "net profit") from first window and by clicking simply moves into 2nd window. Next he click "subtract button" and a minus sign appear in front of "netprofit" in 2nd window and then selects "tax" from first window and moves it to 2nd window. Next he clicks "divide button with / sign on it" and then clicks  "total assets" from first window . Next he clicks save and winow prompts to assign a name to out put of the above..user names it as average profit over assets and saves it into new table. The output in table therefore will be processed based on this custom formula creation window and we can create complex formulas and save thier output and extract as required. The formula we created in above example is as under:

(Net profit before tax- tax)/total assets = Average net profit over assets.

Please guide on highlevel, how i can accomplish this . Also.tell me if there is an Api that can help achieve this quickly or I need to do all coding from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one solution is to implement the window using checkbox list for colums pulled from db and embed them in scroll down div.

Next for all selections made take them and echo in a formula feild. For each add or subtract or multiply or divide button ..take respective values i.e + ,  - , × , ÷ and echo them in respective field. Once the formula is constructed .. post it and store in a new variable $ result. Next use it in a function or simply save/ insert it into a new table called formulas. Next extract values from the table and display/ echo on screen.

Any suggestions??? Am i thinking correctly?